# Lego Mindsotrms RCX 1.0 CPU

Tags: microcontroller, mindstorms

I am working on a project and I need to know what is the exact model number of the CPU that is in the Lego Mindstorms RCX 1.0 . It would be nice if you listed the specs of the CPU, beacause I am looking for its MIPS performance.

Comment: Welcome to Robotics! Answer to your question was in the first link in Google after typing "Lego Mindsotrms RCX 1.0 CPU". Next time, before posting a question, please remember to put some research effort yourself.

Answer (score 1):

From wikipedia follows, that it is a 8-bit Renesas/Hitachi H8/300 16 MHz CPU with 32KB RAM.

Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lego_Mindstorms

Answer (score -1):

I tried looking it up on wikipedia, but there was only the group of processors listed in the article and not the exact CPU model, so I could not find out its specs, because there are multiple CPU of the kind, mentioned in the wikipedia article.